# A more optimise way to iterate through JToken properties?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am iterating through JToken properties and if a key value equal a certain string then it will do a specific action.

```
foreach (JToken type in typeList)
                            {

                                if (type["type"].Value<string>() == "Car")
                                {
                                    Do Something...
                                }
                                else if (type["type"].Value<string>() == "Truck")
                                {
                                    Do Something...
                                } ....
```

Is there a better way to write this as a have a fair few different object types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A switch statement perhaps... because in this case a switch statement would be more effective because it would stop when it hits the "found" value rather than go through all the `ifs` comparisons unless you return in them, then I doubt you'll make anything much efficient - not noticeably for sure.

```
switch(type["type"].Value<string>())
{
    case "Car":
       Do Something...
       break; // (or ) reaturn xxx (or ) go to xxx.

}
```

Comment: Yeah I was about to change it into a case but I thought i'd check if someone could provide a more efficient process :P

Comment: @Mask-dCodex In this case a switch statement would be more effective because it would stop when it hits the "found" value rather than go through all the `ifs`.

Comment: Yes I agree, I already made a change. Was hoping to create a whole new method to perform this action or maybe 1-2 liner :)

Comment: @Mask-dCodex You can create a dictionary of the types such as "Car" and "Truck" and as a value in the dictionary a reference to delegate. But that might be an overkill for this and completely not necessary - definitively not making it more efficient :)